# Jquery not detecting click after appending new html

Tags: jquery, append, click

I have a text box that is using live search functionality. The test HTML works great, click and it adds to the log like it should. Problem is, once I use the search box and new "identical" code is being appended into the #tag-result, click functionality stops working. I'm using the same variation of this code to do other things and it has always worked perfectly...except in this situation.

For example, this exact code, replacing the "tag" relations with "user" works perfectly.

```
// .blur was missed in original edit of this post...
$('#txttagSearch').blur(function() {
    $(this).val('');
    $('#tag-search-results').hide();
})

// remove above code and replace with the following
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    $('#txtTagSearch').val('');
    $('#tag-search-results').hide();
})

// now clicks register and search results hide when they should.
```

```
<div class="form-floating">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtTagSearch" name="txtTagSearch" placeholder="Search to Add Tags" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="txtTagSearch">Search to Add Tags</label>
</div>
<div class="tag-wrapper">
    <div id="tag-search-results">
        <ul id="tag-result">
            <li class="tag-search-click 5">leather</li> /* this click works */
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row gx-2 mt-3">
        <div class="col" id="tag-display">
            <div class="tag" style="background-color: #000;">sunglasses</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('#txtTagSearch').keyup(function() {
    liveSearchTag($(this).val())
    $('#tag-search-results').show();
})

$('#model-tag-results #tag-result').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
})

function liveSearchTag(keyword) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'server/tag-search.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { keyword: keyword },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            const divTagResult = $('#tag-search-results #tag-result');
            let html = '';
            if (result !== null) {
                if (result.length > 0) {
                    $.each(result, function(index, item) {
                        html += '<li class="tag-search-click ' + item['id'] + '">' + item['tag'] + '</li>' // these clicks do not detect?
                    })
                } else {
                    let html = '<li style="padding: 10px;">NO RESULT FOUND</li>';
                }
            } else {
                let html = '<li style="padding: 10px;">NO RESULT FOUND</li>';
            }
            divTagResult.html(html);
        }
    })
}

$('#tag-search-results').on('click','.tag-search-click',function() {
    console.log('test');
    var tagID = $(this).attr('class').replace('tag-search-click ','');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'server/tag-result.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { code: tagID },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#tag-display').append('test');
            $('#txtTagSearch').val('');
            $('#txtTagSearch').blur();
            $('#tag-search-results').hide();
        }
    })
})
```

Tried using multiple click methods...

```
$('#tag-search-results').on('click','.tag-search-click',function() {
$(document).on('click','.tag-search-click',function() {
$('.tag-search-click').(function() {
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: `$('#tag-search-results').on('click','.tag-search-click',function() {` should workhttps://jsbin.com/wulijekeri/1/edit?html,js,console,output. The code you show in the code block above doesn't even react on clicking on the item https://jsbin.com/xureriyexu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Your test environment doesn't have the click event code, it's missing; although it is in my code block. Scroll to the bottom. Once I add the code to your test, everything works actually. But for some reason won't on a live server.

Comment: Well, then it's even simpler - you're *hiding the container*. So yes - the click listener that tries to match items in that container won't work. Because the container isn't there. You're adding a different item elesehwere that doesn't match any of what the click handler would be matching. Neither is the parent "tag-search-results", nor does the new item have the class "tag-search-click". Either you need to adjust what you match for your handler, so you need to change the selectors, or alternatively make sure you are adding things such that the selectors would match the newly added DOM.

Comment: Starting diging a bit. Found a missed piece of code that hides #tag-search-results on blur. Once I remove that, everything works just fine. What gets me, it works on another page just fine. Now when I click one of the dynamically generated results, it does what it's supposed to and hides the #tag-search-results just fine. I'll have to find another way to solve hiding it if the users clicks off the search box. At least this gets it working and points me to a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I missed some `jQuery` in the original post. The `.hide()` on click wasn't what was causing the clicks to not register. The `.blur()` with `.hide()` was causing the issues. Below is the bad code I missed, and the code I'm now using to hide and clear the search results. Everything is now working perfectly. Hopefully this will help. Thanks VLAZ!!

```
    // .blur was missed in original edit of this post...
$('#txttagSearch').blur(function() {
    $(this).val('');
    $('#tag-search-results').hide();
})

// remove above code and replace with the following
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    $('#txtTagSearch').val('');
    $('#tag-search-results').hide();
})

// now clicks register and search results hide when they should.
```